# Python over JavaScript? (Facts, please)

Tags: javascript, python

I recently learned JavaScript an all of the sudden I hear about Python...

Should I go learn Python or just stick with my basic JavaScript knowledge?

If you have some "facts" I would love to hear them! Like efficiency, difficultylevel and so on, an so on...

Thanks :)

Comment: when I saw the title I immediately thought of http://skulpt.org

Comment: A hint: Say what you want to accomplish. If it needs to run in a browser window I'd definitely use Javascript.

Comment: @Eli Bendersky: holy hell that is kinda awesome

Comment: Apple are definitely better than orange. It has wider range of friendly cultivator and they are easy to eat.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.visitmix.com/labs/gestalt/samples/getting.started/02_python.html  If you don't mind using a little Silverlight/.NET framework, that's a good option if you want Python in the browser.  (Look at the source, more importantly)

Comment: @EliBendersky meh, now that we have ES2015 I like it a lot better

Comment: What if you want to write a service/API that can be consumed by different other applications, one of the targets being a web app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're just learning a language, then there is none better than Python.  It's an easy language to pick up.  It's well documented.  It's associated with a large, active, and friendly community.  Since it's a scripting language, you can easily try stuff out and immediately see the results.  You can also build up from programming basics, starting by learning functions and then moving into classes.

Javascript is the bane of many a programmer's existences. It's easy enough to learn, and is good for small scripts which is what is was designed for. But once you start making anything big, it becomes hard to keep track of. That's why language modifications like [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), [Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) and [Dart](http://dartlang.org/) have emerged.

As noted by spinon, these programming languages were used in very different ways. Python is a general scripting language, which can sometimes be used to do server-side work. Javascript used to be solely used for building interactivity on web pages. Nowadays, however, it also becomes popular in server-side and desktop applications as [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

Comment: I would say JavaScript is very advanced, if you find a large project difficult to keep track of then you are not maintaining your resources properly. A framework can help there, see http://www.sproutcore.com as a great example of how easy a large project can be. Even if you are not using an advanced library a copy of JavaScript the Good Parts http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0596517742/wrrrldwideweb will keep you on track.

Comment: Holy sh**, @Pullets Forever! Have you seen one of sproutcores external javascript files? I wouldn't excactly call that easy ;) It took me about 5 minutes scrolling down while I was not reading, just holding down the little scroll-arrow (button-right corner) :D

Comment: Are you talking about a built SproutCore project or the source code? The files I use every day are very easy to modify since they are divided into many smaller files by MVC, logical function, and finally object.

Comment: NOTE: This is a very outdated response; javascript has grown up quite a bit lately, and projects like node and angularjs make it much easier/better to use on big projects (in and outside the server).  Also note that the v8 javascript interpreter is quite a bit faster than standard python.  I love python and I still use it more than any other language because of its great libraries, but the comments about javascript just aren't true.

Comment: the other important thing is that ES2015 modules are much easier to use (just relative file paths, and no `__init__.py`) and npm is also much more convenient (deps are installed locally, multiple versions of the same package are supported, no need to use something like `pyenv`, etc.)

Comment: deleting because this response is so outdated

Comment: nevermind - I can't delete it because it's the accepted answer. You still around @Latze?

Comment: The core of JavaScript is a lot simpler than Python in various ways.  No distinction between tuples and lists.  No distinction between objects and dicts.  `a.b` and `a['b']` do the same thing.  No special syntax to learn for named arguments; you just pass an object argument with the property names you want.  CommonJS and ES2015 modules are simpler to use (no `__init__.py`, `pyenv`, you can require by relative paths, etc).  I think there are fewer things for a beginner to learn in JavaScript than Python.

Answer (score 15):

The two are generally used quite differently. Javascript is primarily used as a client side scripting language vs python which is a server based language. So in a website you could use both. But not sure if this is what you were wondering.

Comment: This is simply not true anymore, in 2014. See [NodeJs](http://nodejs.org/).

Comment: JavaScript and Python are both general scripting language, at least in 2015 it is.

Answer (score 4):

The key fact is that Javascript is very hard to ever change (because of billions of old implementations existing in browsers), so design errors made in early (and frantically hurried;-) stages are still with the language today.  (See Crockford's [Javascript: the good parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748) for a reasonable discussion by a JS expert and enthusiast about the good and bad parts thereof).  This might change if something like a `use strict;` directive ever makes its way into ECMAscript (though programming in ways that support old, and often buggy, browsers, will *still* be like pulling teeth -- like writing Python code that runs unchanged all the way from Python 1.0 to 3.1 would be!-).

Python is deployed in more traditional ways, so gradual language changes have enhanced it over the years (it was also designed with less hurry, and [[arguably, not "a fact";-)]] ended up with a better design from the start, in many respects).

As a result, Javascript (so far) has not enjoyed much success "server side", where programmers get a choice (even though they still have to use JS for "browser side" code). But there's nothing intrinsic to that.  JS is by far the most widely deployed language in the world (those billions of browsers...), huge investments are made in it by many companies and open source groups in competing implementations and supporting frameworks (Python's no slouch at that either, but the difference is still there), practical improvements (speed, warnings) keep piling up on JS's side as a consequence (even though the language proper can't improve).

With strict self-imposed programming discipline (enforced e.g. by Crockfor's "lint" program for JS) and a good supporting framework (jQuery, Dojo, Closure, ...) and tools (Firefox has maybe the best add-ons for JS tracing and debugging, but other browsers are rushing in that direction too), JS has become usable in recent years.  Probably one of these days a fast server-side implementation (probably with "use strict;" or the like enforced, once that's officially blessed;-) will start gaining a substantial foothold, just because so many web programmers already have some JS knowledge (they have to, to make good web apps).

Note that much of JS's bad rep (beyond the acknowledge "bad parts that can't be removed";-) comes from stuff that doesn't really "belong" to JS as a language: buggy implementations, the mess that the HTML DOM can often be (esp. with buggy browser impementations), etc.  There is no reason a future server-side deployment should reproduce these maddening defects!-)

Comment: This answer is way out of date, you should probably just delete it.  ES2015 added tons of language features, and people have developed the extremely sophisticated Babel transpiler to enable early adoption, proving JavaScript is capable of changing just as much as Python.  JS is also widely used on the server side now.

Comment: Totally agree with you @Andy.

Answer (score 3):

Python’s a good second language to learn after JavaScript, as they have a reasonable number of similarities, e.g.

- they’re both memory-managed
- they have similar data structures — JavaScript’s objects and arrays are much like Python’s dictionaries and arrays
- they’re both used quite a lot for web-related work — JavaScript in the browser and in server-side contexts like node.js, Python in web frameworks like Django.

However, Python’s object-oriented... stuff is quite different to JavaScript’s protoype-based object-oriented stuff.

If the only programming you do is manipulating web pages within the web browser, then Python won’t be of any direct use to you (only JavaScript runs in browsers at the moment). But learning another programming language generally gives you new ways to think about the languages you already know. Learning Python could help you write better JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is **primarily for client-side** ( browser ), Python is primarily used for **server-side** - so they serve different needs ( disregarding the Python to JS converters and all ).

I would recommend learning Python though, as it influenced ECMAScript and the syntax is very similar, both are object oriented, both are great languages.

**2018 Update:** I would still recommend learning Python over Javascript as a first language because it's just that much of a more beautiful, elegant language... although Javascript can now be used for both server-side and client-side thanks to node.js thus making it more useful all-around.

http://hg.toolness.com/python-for-js-programmers/raw-file/tip/PythonForJsProgrammers.html

Comment: You mean like Python on DLR? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163344.aspx

Comment: JavaScript can be client side. It isn't inherently client side. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript

Comment: @David, @Paul - in most cases it's used as client-side.

Comment: @meder: very true, although the server-side JavaScript trend seems to be upward, not downward, so it’s worth mentioning.

Comment: Yes, Python can actually be used on the client side with gestalt and the dlr like `<script type="text/python">window.Alert('Hello World')</script>`  http://ironpython.net/browser/

Comment: @jaco219 , using Javascript :P

Comment: have you heard of node.js?

Comment: @AlekseyBykov - nope :)

Comment: just update your answer and admit javascript is everywhere

Comment: Can you be a bit less rude? Especially to an 8 year old answer. node.js hadn't made a dent in 2010 and that's when this answer was written. It has made a dent thus far, but would you not agree that the statement "Javascript is primarily for the client-side and Python is still primarily for server-side"? still reigns true? 99% of JS that's out there is written for in-browser, not node.js. And node.js hasn't taken over all of the other server-side languages, even in 2018.

Comment: @mederomuraliev while I agree Aleksey's response was rude, "99% of JS that's out there is written for in-browser" is just plain wrong. Here are [10 large companies](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/how-are-10-global-companies-using-node-js-in-production) using node.js in production. Also, the massive [npm registry](https://npmjs.org) consists primarily of packages for node.js, and not for the browser (although some of them are built to be isomorphic between the two). With tools like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) and [react](https://reactjs.org), JavaScript is now more accessible than ever

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is usually used as a client-side scripting language - that is, it gets downloaded and executed by your browser. Python, however, is usually not coupled to the web. it can be used as a server-side scripting language, and for scripts and applications of any kind. But it is *not* a client-side language, and is therefore not directly comparable to Javascript, which has an entirely different audience.

Looking at the language level, Javascript is terrible and dysfunctional (hard to debug, clumsy object-orientation) while Python is beautiful and expressive. This is, of course, subjective :-)

Comment: I'm not sure why everyone is saying Python isn't a client-side language.  It's a general purpose language and can be adapted to any need - with stuff like wxPython, Python can really do wonders on the client. There's a difference between "is not" and "isn't best at".

Comment: “I'm not sure why everyone is saying Python isn't a client-side language.” — I think they mean “client-side” in the sense of “runs in a web browser”. I don’t know of any browser than runs Python like it runs JavaScript.

Comment: Aside from that - there are several python-to-JS "Compilers". PYJS to name one.

Answer (score 1):

IMO Python may be easier to learn (having taught both to intro classes).

Also, one major annoyance of JavaScript is that in runs in your browser. This inherently makes  it much harder to debug problems.

In terms of a production-level language, Python is more of a general purpose programming language, while JavaScript is targeted at building dynamic web applications.

If you want to get into programming, you should definitely learn a more general purpose language such as Java or Python.

Comment: There is growing use of JavaScript as a non-browser, server-side language - see node.js for starters. Not sure why, but there is . . .

Comment: Interesting- i find in-browser javascript much MUCH easier to debug than almost any server-side logic.

Answer (score 1):

For what purpose? Javascript is king in some circles (web development, for instance).

Javascript and Python are not mutually exclusive. Why not learn both?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript and Python are both great languages that are geared toward different problems.

JavaScript knowledge is invaluable when dealing with the web, writing web pages, and poking around in html DOM.

Python is a scripting language that is great for a host of things on any machine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Do you want to program in a language that specifically targets web browsers? Stick with Javascript

Do you want to write... well anything besides for web browsers? Learn Python.

Python is an excellent beginner language that's not just a beginner language. Google uses it, NASA uses it, and many, many other organizations use Python.

Answer (score 0):

Along with Python generally being server-side and JavaScript client-side, Python was designed to not only be easy to learn, but also easy to read, and to encourage a more productive environment.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to ask, then I would say no since you don't have a need in mind for its usage.